# What are some relevant A.I. techniques for programming a flock of entities?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Specifically, I am talking about programming for this contest: http://www.nodewar.com/about

The contest involves you facing other teams with a swarm of spaceships in a two dimensional world. The ships are constrained by a boundary (if they exit they die), and they must continually avoid moons (who pull the ships in with their gravity). The goal is to kill the opposing queen.

I have attempted to program a few, relatively basic techniques, but I feel as though I am missing something fundamental.

For example, I implemented some of the boids behaviours (http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/), but they seemed to lack a... goal, so to speak.

Are there any common techniques (or, preferably, combinations of techniques) for this sort of game?

**EDIT**

I would just like to open this up again with a bounty since I feel like I'm still missing critical pieces of information. The following is my NodeWar code:

```
boundary_field = (o, position) ->
  distance = (o.game.moon_field - o.lib.vec.len(o.lib.vec.diff(position, o.game.center)))
  return distance

moon_field = (o, position) ->
  return o.lib.vec.len(o.lib.vec.diff(position, o.moons[0].pos))

ai.step = (o) ->
  torque = 0;
  thrust = 0;
  label = null;

  fields = [boundary_field, moon_field]

  # Total the potential fields and determine a target.
  target = [0, 0]
  score = -1000000
  step = 1
  square = 1

  for x in [(-square + o.me.pos[0])..(square + o.me.pos[0])] by step
    for y in [(-square + o.me.pos[1])..(square + o.me.pos[1])] by step
      position = [x, y]
      continue if o.lib.vec.len(position) > o.game.moon_field
      value = (fields.map (f) -> f(o, position)).reduce (t, s) -> t + s
      target = position if value > score
      score = value if value > score

  label = target

  { torque, thrust } = o.lib.targeting.simpleTarget(o.me, target)  
  return { torque, thrust, label }
```

I may have implemented potential fields incorrectly, however, since all the examples I could find are about discrete movements (whereas NodeWar is continuous and not exact).

The main problem being my A.I. never stays within the game area for more than 10 seconds without flying off-screen or crashing into a moon.

Comment: Can you train offline models?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut No, all of the games I have to run manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily make the boids algorithm play the game of Nodewar, by just adding additional steering behaviours to your boids and/or modifying the default ones. For example, you would add a steering behaviour to avoid the moon, and a steering behaviour for enemy ships (repulsion or attraction, depending on the position between yours and the enemy ship). The weights of the attraction/repulsion forces should then be tweaked (possibly by genetic algorithms, playing different configurations against each other).

I believe this approach would give you already a relatively strong baseline player, to which you can start adding collaborative strategies etc.

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestion (and I really like it), but I am unable to automate the game playing process to use a GA.

Comment: Using the GA is just one option, you can also tune the attraction/repulsion forces manually. But fundamentally, the boids algorithm provides a strong approach for this type of game. Additionally, you can take a look at the Potential Fields (http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/potential-fields/), which is another approach for playing real time strategy game

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I'll accept your answer but I'd still love more suggestions if anyone has alternative approaches. I'll be trying out potential fields this week.

Comment: To clarify, the GA doesn't have to be running during gameplay. It should be used as a separate process (run over hours/days/weeks) to tweak the parameters

Comment: @user1158559 Yes, but the game logic is not open source so I can't actually simulate how the agents will perform programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the best possible flocking behaviour using control theory. We can start by expressing the state of a ship (a vector of positions and velocities) as variable X. We will use x to represent a small deviation from some state X0. For each node, linearize around the state you want the individual ships to be at:

d/dt(X) = f(X - X0)

where X0 is the state you want the ship to be at. f() can be nonlinear (as in the case of your potential field). Close to this point, the  will obey

d/dt(x) = Ax

A is a fixed matrix which you should tweak to achieve stability. Much of the field of control theory tells you how to do this. It's very important to you that A leads to a stable system and that it converges fast. You should now break out MATLAB or GNU Octave. You should also read up on what poles mean in control theory, and Laplace transforms. The poles of the system (eigenvalues of matrix A) will characterize the response of the ship to disturbances of any kind, its stability, and its convergeance speed. It will also tell you whether the ship will move towards X0 or oscillate around X0.

There are several ways of choosing A (You probably don't get full control over A because of the game's limited physics) without having to do much analysis yourself. Two such algorithms are optimal control (You define the cost of controlling the system vs the cost of deviating from X0), and pole placement (You choose where the poles will go).

The state space theory also applies to an entire flock of ships, deviating from the configuration desired by every ship at that point in time. If the system is nonlinear, You might not be able to guarantee that all configurations are stable.

Conclusion:

Use control theory to guarantee individual stability, calculating X0 based on the ships around you, and add a potential field to prevent ships from bumping into eachother and moons.

Disclaimer:

There are several ways of expressing a state space system. This is the simplest but you'll need to express it differently when considering the open loop system (split up A into another 'A' which gives you the physical system and some other matrices which give you the control parameters)

Comment: This sounds pretty cool but it's a bit high level for me as I haven't been introduced to control theory before. I found this: http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=SystemModeling but it would be great if you have any links that got you started!

Comment: This has also been helpful: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/teaching/math332/pdf/chapter1.pdf